# Como esconder a barra do InAppBrowser?

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, ionic, inappbrowser

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile que basicamente carrega uma interface web dentro do app através do plugin Inappbrowser. A ideia do projeto é exatamente simular o funcionamento de um app. Tudo funciona normalmente, porém o plugin Inappbrowser exibe uma barra no navegador como no pritscreen abaixo, e preciso que essa barra **não** seja exibida! Alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer isso?

[image: App]
Esse é o código que tenho até o momento (A variável **inputUrl** é preenchida pelo usuário em um outro formulário):

```
var url = "http://" + inputUrl + "/mobile";
window.open(url,'_self');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma, ele abrirá o link no navegador interno sem a barra de endereço:

```
// Open in app browser
var url = "http://" + inputUrl + "/mobile";
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
```